# Decrease the False Negative Rate in signal prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I'm currently working on a project in estimating signal by using some classification learning algorithms, such as logistics regression and random forest using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/).

I'm now using the confusion matrix to estimate the performance of different algorithms in prediction, and I found there was common problem for both algorithms. That is, in all cases, although the accuracy of algorithms seems relatively good (around 90% - 93%),  the total number of FN are pretty high comparing to TP (FNR < 3% ). Does any one has clue about why I'm having this kind of issue in my prediction problem. If possible, can you give me some hints regarding how to possibly solve this problem?

Thanks for reply and help in advance.

Updates:
The dataset is extremely imbalanced (8:1), with in total around 180K observations. I already tested several re-sampling methods, such as OSS, SMOTE(+Tomek or +ENN), but neither of them returns good results. In both cases, although the recall goes up from 2.5% to 20%, the precision decreases significantly (from 60% to 20%).

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Scikit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an imbalanced dataset, where one of your classes has many more examples than your other class.

One solution is to give an higher cost of misclassifying the class with less examples.

This question in Cross Validated covers many approaches to your problem:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/class-imbalance-in-supervised-machine-learning

**EDIT:**

Given that you are using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) you can, as a first approach, set the parameter `class_weight` to `balanced` on your [Logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Comment: Exactly, the dataset is extremely imbalanced (around 8:1). I already tried some re-sampling methods, like SMOTE, but neither of them returns good results.

Comment: Can you give us more information then? Like post the confusion matrix and some samples of your data?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I also tried to the class_weight to balanced, but the accuracy goes down to around 75%.

Comment: The data is sort of confidential for some reason, so I will post the confusion matrix.